# What is the name of the special parsha read on the shabbos before purim?

Tags: shabbat, adar

What is the parasha that we read on the shabbos before purim called?

Comment: Did you try to solve this on your own before asking? Perhaps try Google?

Comment: Why did someone upvote this question?

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps b/c of "rachamnut" to a neophyte?

Answer (score 3):

On the *Shabas* before *Purim*, we read the regular weekly *parasha*, which varies; next year (2017 Gregorian, 5777 Jewish) it will be *T'tzave*. Most weeks, after concluding the regular weekly *parasha*, we repeat the last part of it; this second time around is commonly called "*maftir*". Some special weeks, we read a section of the Torah relevant to that week as *maftir* instead of repeating the last part of the weekly *parasha*. The *Shabas* before *Purim* is one such week, when *maftir* is Deut. 25:17–19, "*Zachor…*".

**"[TL;DR](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tl;dr#English)" version:** Whatever the regular weekly *parasha* is, with Deut. 25:17–19 instead of the usual *maftir*.

---

Source: Many years of looking at calendars and listening to Torah readings.

Answer (score 0):

Parshat Zachor . See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Shabbat#The_Four_Parshiyot) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

A source, as a footnote to the previous answers:
Mishna Megila 3, 4:

> רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ אֲדָר שֶׁחָל לִהְיוֹת בְּשַׁבָּת, קוֹרִין בְּפָרָשַׁת שְׁקָלִים (שמות ל). חָל לִהְיוֹת בְּתוֹךְ הַשַּׁבָּת, מַקְדִּימִין לְשֶׁעָבַר וּמַפְסִיקִין לְשַׁבָּת אַחֶרֶת. בַּשְּׁנִיָּה , זָכוֹר (דברים כה).
>
> If the first day of Adar falls on Shabbat, they read Parashat Shekalim. If it falls on an other day of the week, they read Shekalim on the previous Shabbat and interrupt the sequence for the next. **On the second Shabbat**<sup>1</sup> (of the sequence), **they read ZACHOR**<sup>2</sup>.
>
> <sup>1</sup> Ykar Tosfot Yom Tov in name of Ran:
>   בַּשְּׁנִיָּה. לִשְׁקָלִים אוֹ לַהַפְסָקָה.
>   The second after Shekalim or after the Shabbat of interruption.
>
> <sup>2</sup> Bartenura:
>   כְּדֵי שֶׁתִּקָּרֵא פָּרָשַׁת זָכוֹר בַּשַּׁבָּת הַסְּמוּכָה לְפוּרִים, לִסְמֹךְ מְחִיַּת עֲמָלֵק לִמְחִיַּת הָמָן
>   so that **Parashat Zachor will be read on the Shabbat adjacent to Purim**, in way to juxtapose the remembrance of **Amalek** and the Remembrance of **Haman**.

For the maftir (A passage Prophets from Prophets who is similar to the parasha, which was read instead of the parasha at time of Antioch, when he prohibited public reading of Torah. Passed this period, Jewish don't leave this custom) "**I remember what made you Amalek**"(Samuel 1, 15) (summary from Bartenura and Ykar Tosfot Yom Tov)

As mentioned by @msh210  Parashat Zachor is read after the parashat Hashavua of (following their order of the Sefer Tora) as Maftir (usually in a second Sefer Tora, if the synagogue has more than 1 Sefer Tora)

See Shulchan Aruch [Orach Chayim 685, 1-2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x3061)

---

The SA in Sayif 7 reading of Zachor with a Minyan is regarded by some Poskim as a scriptural commandment. One of the explanations written in Magen Avraham is from the Gemara Megila 18a:

> If one reads (the Megila) it by heart, he has not performed his obligation. Whence this rule? - Raba said: We explain the expression zekirah in one passage from its use in another. It is written here (Esther), And these days shall be nizkarim [remembered] and it is written elsewhere (Exodus), Write this le-zikaron [for a memorial] in the book. Just as there it was to be **in a book**, so here it must be in a book. But how do we know that this 'nizkarim' implies 'uttering'? Perhaps it means mere reading with the eyes? - Do not imagine such a thing, since it his been taught: 'Remember' [zakor]. Am I to say, this means only with the mind? When the text says, thou shalt not forget, the injunction against mental forgetfulness is already given. What then am I to make of 'remember'? This must mean, **by utterance**.

Despite that it is not the direct topic of the Gemara, we can understand from it that Zachor Et Asher Assa Lecha Amalek is a reading by utterance in a book. Magen Avraham explained that there is no proof that it should be read at this shabbat and that they need to read this specific Parasha. He stated that the reading of "Vayavo Amalek" at Purim may be valuable to fulfill this duty of "Zachor".

Comment: adding reference on Shulchan Aruch. cancelling the expression "Kesidran" that is not appropriate, pasting Gemara for source of the reading Zachor is a scriptural obligation.